# bmatrix, how to give details after particular row bracket[ ]?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices, mathtools

I am new to LaTeX. I want matrix like in `bmatrix`

[image: matrix]

```
[1 1 1] R1=R1-R2  (Row1= Row 1 - Row 2)
 1 1 1  R2<-R1+R3
 1 1 1
```

I want "R1=R1-R2" after the matrix [1 1 1] but when i add this its goes to next line.(I want to write after the [ ] bracket) how to do that?

Comment: You may want to look at the `gauss` package

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newdimen\eliminationwd

\newenvironment{elimination}
 {\global\eliminationwd=0pt\bmatrix}
 {\endbmatrix\hspace{1em}\hspace{\eliminationwd}}

\newcommand{\ops}[1]{%
  \sbox0{$#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\eliminationwd
    \global\eliminationwd=\wd0
  \fi
  \hfil\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{1em}\box0}\hfilneg
}

\begin{document}
\[
\left|
\begin{elimination}
1 &  0 & -1 &  0 &  4 \\
0 &  1 &  2 &  0 &  1 \ops{R_2\gets R_2-2R_1} \\
0 &  2 &  4 &  1 & -1 \ops{R_3\gets R_1+R_3} \\
1 & -1 & -2 & -2 &  5 \ops{R_4\gets R_4-R_1}
\end{elimination}
\right|
\]
\end{document}
```

I used `\left|` and `\right|` just to show that the spacing is good. The macro `\ops` measures its contents and, if necessary, updates the length stored in `\eliminationwd`. Then it typesets the argument in a zero width box aligned with the right margin of the cell and sticking out to the right. The necessary horizontal space is taken care of after the matrix is typeset by `\endbmatrix`.

[image]

If you change the definition of `\ops` into

```
\newcommand{\ops}[1]{%
  \sbox0{$\scriptstyle#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\eliminationwd
    \global\eliminationwd=\wd0
  \fi
  \hfil\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{1em}\box0}\hfilneg
}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: Simple and beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

A  simple way to do that with the `blockarray` package. I also use the `nccmath` package for its `medsize` environment, in order to have comments/details in smaller size font than the main formula (~80 % of `displaystyle`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{array, multirow, bigdelim}%
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\setlength\BAextrarowheight{3pt}
\[ \begin{blockarray}{[ccccc] >{\medsize}l <{\endmedsize}}%\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}
  1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 4 & \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 &\mathrm{R_2 = R_2-2R_1} \\
  0 & 2 & 4 & 1 & -1 & R_3 ← R_1 + R_3\\
  1 & -1 & -2 & -2 & 5 & R_4 ← R_4-R_1
  \end{blockarray} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]